# Drag and drop docking

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, dock

Is there a way to create a dynamic dock in extjs ? Basically I need to drop the draggable panel in the desired region, just like the image I attached.[image]

[image]

Comment: You are able to add [`DragSource`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.dd.DragSource.html) and [`DropTarget`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.dd.DropTarget.html) to the parent element of the docked items you want to move. Using [`setDock`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-setDock) you can change the dock position depending on the drop position.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your response. Can u please show me a small working example ?

Comment: Did you find any anwer?